# Jquery Ajax that change content of html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I'd like you to give help for this problem, I have table in jsp page that loads data from server,but my question is, when ever i write number in input text box and press enter, I want to load a new list of data from server(servlet) and change the content of the same row with it using jquery ajax with json. 
and this is my code.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.name1').keypress(function(event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
            var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
            var kwd=$(this).val();
            var name=$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').html();

            $.get('showRate',{name:name,kwd:kwd},function(responseJson) {
                if(responseJson != null) {
                    $.each(responseJson,function(key,value) {
                        alert(responseJson);
                    });             
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form action="showKwh" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="show"/>
    <table id="adminTable" class="detailsTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th colspan="4">Kilowat Entry</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tableHeading">
            <td>customer id</td>
            <td>name</td>

            <td>group</td>
            <td>kwh</td>

            <td>faraq</td>
            <td>lacag</td>
            <td>tax</td>
            <td>normal</td>
            <td>abnormal</td>
            <td>kwd</td>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach  var="cust" items="${customerKwh}" varStatus="iter">
            <tr class="${((iter.index % 2) == 1) ? 'lightBlue' : 'white'} tableRow">
                <td>${cust.id}</td>
                <td >${cust.name}</td>
                <td >${cust.type}</td>

                <td >${cust.kwh}</td>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt"  value="" class="name1"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: what issue you are facing with current code ?

Comment: when i write some in the textbox and press enter nothing happens, but what i want is, whenever I write in textbox and press enter I want to use the values of txtbox and first td as parameters of the ajax, and then data from server makes change to the content of the current row

Comment: let me tell you, I know how to deal with behind the ajax(i mean the servlet), but my issue is how to trigger ajax with these parameter using keypress(Enter) and data from server get changes the current row. please your answer is helpful for me. thanks brothers.

Comment: thanks brother, but how can I change the content of the current row with data from server using Ajax,

Answer (score 1):

A small correction in your JS code is needed. Actually while getting the **name** first time, you are trying to find td inside the INPUT itself and I guess you want to find first TD of that TR for the same.

The problem is, you are declaring the `var name` again. Though it should work fine as it's written.

Well here is the udated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.name1').keypress(function (event) {

        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') {
            var kwd = $(this).val();
            var name = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();

            $.get('showRate', {
                name : name,
                kwd : kwd
            }, function (responseJson) {
                if (responseJson != null) {
                    $.each(responseJson, function (key, value) {

                        alert(responseJson);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If still not work, there would be some issue with the ajax URL. You can check the same on Network in browser inspector.

Comment: thanks brother, also I want to know how to change the current row data with the data from server in the ajax where I show "alert". and and after that get focus on the next input

Comment: Sure mate, Can I have the JSON response what you get from the server?

Comment: response.setContentType("application/json");
            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String strKwd=request.getParameter("kwd");
            int lacag;
            int kwd=Integer.parseInt(strKwd);
            if(kwd>5){
                lacag = kwd*6;
            }else
            {
                lacag=5;
            }
            
             String showLacag=new Gson().toJson(lacag);
             response.getWriter().write(showLacag);

Comment: response.setContentType("application/json");
            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String strKwd=request.getParameter("kwd");
            int lacag;
            int kwd=Integer.parseInt(strKwd);
            if(kwd>5){
                lacag = kwd*6;
            }else
            {
                lacag=5;
            }
            
             String showLacag=new Gson().toJson(lacag);
             response.getWriter().write(showLacag);